# qemu-system-aarch64: kvm_init_vcpu failed: Invalid argument

Tags: android, linux, qemu, arm64

Successfully integrated QEMU in my device and tried to launch cuttlefish but it is getting "qemu-system-aarch64: kvm_init_vcpu failed: Invalid argument" related issues.

$ qemu-system-aarch64 --version

QEMU emulator version 4.2.1
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

Just for more clarity , KVM is enabled in my device (Linux OS ARM64 processor).

$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     kvm        10, 232 Nov 23 15:43 /dev/kvm

Please find snipped error log :

```
######################################################################
/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64
2023-11-20T22:27:38.422646Z qemu-system-aarch64: kvm_init_vcpu failed: Invalid 
argument
Detected unexpected exit of monitored subprocess /usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64
Subprocess /usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 (2336) has exited with exit code 1
failed to read from socket, retry.
failed to read from socket, retry.
Start modem simulator, server_fds: 64, Sim type: normal
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:7200
Metrics started
Metrics host received: VMStart
######################################################################
```

I am stuck in between and could not understand why I am facing this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try -cpu host

That worked for me

Comment: Can you please provide the exact command.I have ran "HOME=$PWD ./bin/launch_cvd --vm_manager=qemu_cli" this command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).